# Html with Javascript validation

Tags: javascript, html

The following program does not work as expected. I want to check the username and password, if they are correct then i need to navigate my page to the mentioned html. 
Even though i gave the correct username and password i am getting incorrect values. Please correct the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>License Management System-Login</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="00CCCC">
<h1 style="text-align:center">License Management System</h1>
<h3 style="text-align:center">Login</h3>
<div align="center">
<form method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>User Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" onclick="validate()"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function validate(){
    var username = document.getElementsByName("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementsByName("password").value;

    if ( username === "admin" && password === "admin"){
        alert ("Login successfully");
        window.location.assign("/License_Mgnt_System/FirstPage.html");//redirecting to other page
        return true;
    }
    else{
            alert("Enter the correct details");
            return false;
        }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Fine, but by hitting `ctrl+u` anyone can get your password and your username, since it's javascript and it will be fully visible by everyone. Also, using a `form` and a `submit` you will reload the page, therefore your click event won't be executed. You should rather check username and password in PHP or whatever  server-side language you're using, NOT javascript

Comment: Okay. I want this code to work. can you please give me a solution?

Comment: Sure, can I use PHP for your specific case?

Comment: First - Usernames and Passwords should ***NEVER*** be stored in JavaScript.  Second, I have a problem with your statement *"Please correct the code."* We're not here to do work for you or to debug your code.  We are here to help you with specific problems or to help you understand how or why something happens the way it does.  I think maybe you have the wrong idea about this site.

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByName returns a collection. You need to add [0] to get the value of username and password.

```
var username = document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value;
var password = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getElementsByName systax is not correct. use below code and you will get proper value. :)

**Solution**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>        
        <title>License Management System-Login</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validate() {
                var username = document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value;
                var password = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;

                if (username === "admin" && password === "admin") {
                    alert("Login successfully");
                    window.location.assign("/License_Mgnt_System/FirstPage.html");//redirecting to other page
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Enter the correct details");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="00CCCC">
        <h1 style="text-align:center">License Management System</h1>
        <h3 style="text-align:center">Login</h3>
        <div align="center">
            <form method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>User Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password:</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" onclick="validate()"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `getElementById("id")`

and add `id` attributes to the controls. Remove name attributes.